# what is the difference between inheritance and collaboration diagrams?

Tags: inheritance, uml, collaboration

I've just generated a doxygen documentation for LLVM using python-sphinx. I'm not very good at UML. I understand inheritance diagrams, but I'm not very clear about collaboration diagrams. Explanations that I found online are not very clear.

I'd really appreciate if someone could show the difference between the two using a specific example.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "inheritance" diagram. I guess you mean a [class diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html) where you can see inheritance drawn as a line with a hollow triangle. This is a static display of a class model. It shows methods and attributes of classes as well as how the classes are related to each other (not just generalization but all kinds of dependencies).

A collaboration diagram is the behavioral part. There are two exchangeable versions: [communication](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/communication-diagrams.html) and [sequence](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) diagrams. While the first puts a focus on "which object collaborate in a certain use case" the sequence puts the focus on "which messages are exchanged in which order" for a scenario. Both use messages and you can convert one into the other.

To be true, there are more than the above. But those are the most important when you start.